# Integer Logic - The well ordering principle

Tags: logic, integers

I've been stumped with understanding the well ordering principle. When presented with a problem such as:

$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~n  \in\mathbb Z$ (integers), prove that there is no integer $x$ such that $n < x < n+1$

I assume it is similar to $0 < x < 1$ which is not true. My question is, how would one effectively prove the statement above assuming that we have a set $S = \{n  \in\mathbb Z \mid n < x < n+1\}$?

Comment: It depends on how integer is defined.  But presumably addition is closed on the integers so that would imply x-n is an integer and 0 <x-n <1. Presumably integers are somehow defined so that 1 is the smallest positive integer?

Comment: Okay,  every set of integers has a smallest element.  So let 0 <x <1 then $1>x>x^2>x^3.... $ so $x^{n+1}<x^n $ so the set of powers of x has no smallest member.  So 1 is the smallest positive integer.

Comment: I suppose you could let S be the set of  positive integers x such that n <x <n+1 for some n.  Let y be the smallest such element of S.  Then m <y <m+1.  But then m-1 <y-1 <m so x-1 $\le$ 0 so 0 < y $\le$ 1 so y=1 that means 0 <m <1 which is impossible. So S is empty.